# Google Calender Api v3 .net Send email notification when attendee replies to event

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar Api v3 for .Net in my project. I need to create event and send notification when any attendee replies to event ("Yes", "No"). I read the api documentation and tried what it says. Below is the code that i create service account credential and create event with organizer and creator information.

I have the domain "example.net" and trying to create event with organizer that has email "organizer@example.net" , both organizer and attendees can be from different domains like "gmail, outlook".

But whenever i create the event, api automatically sends email to attendees about event information, but organizer looks like "calendar@example-calendar.iam.gserviceaccount.com" which is defined in "calendar.json" file. So whenever attendee replies the event, organizer cannot get email about what an attendee replied for event. I couldnt able to set organizer to "organizer@example.com", it is always "calendar@example-calendar.iam.gserviceaccount.com".

Please look at the code below and tell me how can i set the organizer,creator of event to "organizer@example.com" (which also can be in different email address with different domain like gmail, outlook), or how can i make google calendar sends email notification to event organizer when any attendee replies to event (yes or no)

```
  private static Event SendCalendarInvitation()
    {
        try
        {
            string credPath = @"C:\calendar.json";

            var json = File.ReadAllText(credPath);
            var cr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PersonalServiceAccountCred>(json); 

            var xCred = new ServiceAccountCredential(new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(cr.client_email)
            {
                Scopes = new[] {
                    CalendarService.Scope.Calendar
                }
            }.FromPrivateKey(cr.private_key));

            // Create the service

            CalendarService service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = xCred
            });

            Event calendarEvent = new Event
            {
                Summary = "Example Event",
                Location = "Los Angeles",
                Description = "Description",
                Start = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 6, 2, 10, 0, 0),
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                End = new EventDateTime()
                {
                    DateTime = new DateTime(2018, 6, 2, 12, 0, 0),
                    TimeZone = "America/Los_Angeles"
                },
                Attendees = new List<EventAttendee>()
                {
                    new EventAttendee() { Email = "organizer@example.com", Organizer = true},
                    new EventAttendee() { Email = "attendee@gmail.com"}
                },
                Creator = new Event.CreatorData()
                {
                    Email = "organizer@example.com",
                    DisplayName = "Organizer"
                },
                Organizer = new Event.OrganizerData()
                {
                    Email = "organizer@example.com",
                    DisplayName = "Organizer"
                },
                Reminders = new Event.RemindersData()
                {
                    UseDefault = false,
                    Overrides = new List<EventReminder>()
                    {
                        new EventReminder()
                        {
                            Method = "email",
                            Minutes = 30
                        },
                        new EventReminder()
                        {
                            Method = "email",
                            Minutes = 14400
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            Event calendarEventResult = null;

            var statusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted;
            try
            {
                var request = service.Events.Insert(calendarEvent, "primary");
                request.SendNotifications = true;
                calendarEventResult = request.Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            }
            return calendarEventResult;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Events have a single organizer which is the calendar containing the main copy of the event. Events can also have multiple attendees. An attendee is usually the primary calendar of an invited user.

If the service account is set to be the organizer then you are sending the events on behalf of the service account.  Which is a dummpy user.   When it invites a user to an even the user will be notified that the person who created the event has added them in this case its "calendar@example-calendar.iam.gserviceaccount.com"   There is no way to change this.

I haven't tried this.  But if you do an [Event.patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) and have the service account set your personal account to be organizer it should then send mails from you and not the service account.

```
// Building the initial request.
var request = service.Events.Patch(body, calendarId, eventId);

// Applying optional parameters to the request.                
request = (EventsResource.PatchRequest)SampleHelpers.ApplyOptionalParms(request, optional);

// Requesting data.
return request.Execute();
```

code ripped from [Events sample](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/EventsSample.cs)

**Order of testing this idea.**

1. Create an event.
2. Patch the event updating the organizer to be yourself instead of the service account.
3. Do an event get see wither or not you were able to update this field. Documentation says that it should be writable.
4. Add an attendee to the event.  check what email its sent from.

IF it still doesn't work try setting your email as owner as well as organizer but i am worried the service account wont be able to edit it then.

Comment: When to call this method. After insert method in my function  ?

Comment: You will probably need to run that after you create the event and before you add the people attending the event.  It doesnt apear to be posible to set the organizer when the event is created its going to have to be done after using a patch.

Comment: It didnt work or i couldnt make it. I first created event without attendees and execute insert request (because i need event id to patch) , after insert request executed, i created a patch request in which attendees are added and organizer is added, then executed the patch request. Still organizer is not set in the event. Am i doing wrong?

Comment: One step at a time.  First patch the organizer.  Then check that it did in fact update.   Then try and add a single user and see if you get the correct email address.   Remember i am not even sure this is possible I was never able to get it to work years ago i had to live with the service accout email address.

Comment: It didnt work mails are always sent from service user and organizer is service user. Cannot change organizer email.

Comment: That is the exactly same issue i had a few years ago.  I dont think its possible.  Emails are sent from the user who invites you.   Which i guess in the longrun does make sence.

Comment: Well, is there a way to create notifications (email)for an attendee if any other attendee replies to the event. Only organizer gets email notifications when an attendee replies to event. Is it possible that an attendee also gets notification